# Conditional Animation don't stop

Tags: animation, swiftui

I have a Button with a `scaleEffect(bool1 ? bool2 ? 1.2 : 1 : 1)`.
If `bool1` is false it should be a scaleEffect of 1.
`bool2` is getting toggled `withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5).repeatForever)`.
So if `bool1` is true it should scale between 2 values and if `bool1` is false it should stop but it doesn't.

What is the problem?

Code:

```
struct FullAnimationView: View {
    
    @State var bool1 = false
    @State var bool2 = false

    var body: some View {
            Button {
                bool1.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text(String(bool1))
                    .frame(width: 60, height: 30)
                    .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6).stroke(bool1 ? bool2 ? Color.red : Color.orange : Color.orange))
            }
            .background(bool1 ? bool2 ? .red.opacity(0.3) : .orange.opacity(0.3) : .orange.opacity(0.3))
            .cornerRadius(6)
            .scaleEffect(bool1 ? bool2 ? 1.2 : 1 : 1)
            .onAppear {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5).repeatForever()) {
                   bool2.toggle()
                }
                bool1.toggle()
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your view is animating from the start.  You need to do something to explicitly stop the animation.  One way to do that is to replace your view (that is, your button) with a new one that isn't animating.

Create a `buttonID` as a `UUID` (universally unique identifier) and use it with `.id(buttonID)` on your button.  When you change `buttonID`, SwiftUI will create a new view for you.

When the button is pressed, if `bool1` is `true`, start a new animation, just as you did when the view first appeared.  If `bool1` is `false`, assign a new `buttonID` to create a new view to stop the animation.  Also set `bool2` to `false` so that it is ready to start the new animation.

```
struct FullAnimationView: View {
    
    @State private var bool1 = false
    @State private var bool2 = false
    @State private var buttonID = UUID()
    
    var body: some View {
            Button {
                bool1.toggle()
                if bool1 {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5).repeatForever()) {
                       bool2.toggle()
                    }
                } else {
                    bool2 = false
                    buttonID = UUID()
                }
            } label: {
                Text(String(bool1))
                    .frame(width: 60, height: 30)
                    .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6).stroke(bool1 ? bool2 ? Color.red : Color.orange : Color.orange))
            }
            .background(bool1 ? bool2 ? .red.opacity(0.3) : .orange.opacity(0.3) : .orange.opacity(0.3))
            .cornerRadius(6)
            .scaleEffect(bool1 ? bool2 ? 1.2 : 1 : 1)
            .id(buttonID)
            .onAppear {
                bool1.toggle()
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5).repeatForever()) {
                   bool2.toggle()
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: How did this work for you?